# Cant Convert Observable to Object[]

Tags: javascript, json, angular, rxjs

I want to get **user** data from my JSON server, here is it's data:

```
{

  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "username": "test",
      "password": "test",
      "role": "admin",
      "token":"yRQYnWzskCZUxPwaQupWkiUzKELZ49eM7oWxAQK_ZXw"
    }
  ]
}
```

For this I have used get request, here is my code:

```
@Injectable()
export class FakeBackendInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor,OnInit {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private userData: Http) { }
    private endpoint: string = 'http://localhost:3000/users';
    users: Array<any> = [];
    ngOnInit(){
        this.authService.getUsers()
        .toPromise()
        .then((users: Array<User>) => {
            this.users = users;
            return users;
        });
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        // const users: User[] = [
        //     { id: 1, username: 'test', password: 'test', role: "user" }
        // ];

        const authHeader = request.headers.get('Authorization');
        const isLoggedIn = authHeader && authHeader.startsWith('Bearer fake-jwt-token');

        // wrap in delayed observable to simulate server api call
        return of(null).pipe(mergeMap(() => {

            // authenticate - public
            if (request.url.endsWith('3000/users') && request.method === 'PUT') {
                console.log(this.users);
                const user = this.users.find(x => x.username === request.body.username && x.password === request.body.password);
                if (!user) return error('Username or password is incorrect');
                return ok({
                    id: user.id,
                    username: user.username,
                    role: user.role,
                    token: user.token
                });
            }

            // get all users
            if (request.url.endsWith('/users') && request.method === 'GET') {
                if (!isLoggedIn) return unauthorised();
                return ok(this.users);
            }

            // pass through any requests not handled above
            return next.handle(request);
        }))
            .pipe(materialize())
            .pipe(delay(500))
            .pipe(dematerialize());

        // private helper functions

        function ok(body) {
            return of(new HttpResponse({ status: 200, body }));
        }

        function unauthorised() {
            return throwError({ status: 401, error: { message: 'Unauthorised' } });
        }

        function error(message) {
            return throwError({ status: 400, error: { message } });
        }
    }
}

export let fakeBackendProvider = {
    // use fake backend in place of Http service for backend-less development
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: FakeBackendInterceptor,
    multi: true
};
```

I have changed my logic and tried to use Promises istead of Observable, but in this case i got an  empty array ( it seems that i can't parse received response as User [], instead i got Promise>) and can't receive array of Users, what should i change to parse get request response to User[] array?

Answer (score 2):

In you main component where you are going to be using the data you need to subscribe as its an Observable. so try the following.

```
public users = [];

this.exampleService.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data); // should be your users.
    this.users = data.users;
}, error => {
    console.log(error); // if api returns and error you will get it here  
});
```

**With your edit**

I would still stick with an Observable but that is down to preference. As long as `this.authService.getUsers()` returns an `Observable<IUsers>` this should work fine. Would also recommend making an interface to handle the data with.

```
export interface IUsers
{
    id: number;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    role: string;
    token: string;
}


public users: IUsers[] = [];

public ngOnInit(): void {

    this.authService.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data); // should be your users.
    this.users = data.users;

}, error => {
    console.log(error); // if api returns and error you will get it here  
    }); 

  });
}
```

This should then give you this.users to use within the interceptor. If this does not help please add code for `this.authService.getUsers()`
Hope that helps, comment if you face any issues.

Comment: Hey, thank you for  your response , i think i should't have used Subscription, so i have changed my  logic, but now i have a new problem , i guess i cant parse my response to this array User [],do you have any idea how should i change my logic/code to get normal response?

Comment: added an edit hope that helps, can you confirm for me as im unsure of the top of my head, does the console.log() of data in the subscription fire before the interceptor starts.

Answer (score 0):

use `nullish coalescing` with Behavior Subject. It worked for me if you wanted to use in the template.

(behaviorSubject$ | async) ?? {}